# Connecting html and python, using python flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I have made a  html for with method post, i have used cgi.FieldStorage() in python.
In html there is a line in:

```
<form action="website.py" method="post">
<input type="Sting" name="username" id="username" placeholder ="User Name">
</form>
```

now in  python:

```
import cgi
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
user_name=form.getvalue('username')
#it is giving none and
user=form['username'].value
#it gives key error 'username'
```

what to do now?
I metioned it, and i was expecting the username output as the username entered by user!

Comment: How does Flask factor into any of this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there might be a couple of issues with the code you’ve provided. First, ensure that the type attribute in your HTML input tag is correctly set to **"text"** instead of **"Sting"**. This could be a typo that’s causing the problem.

Here’s the corrected HTML form:

HTML

```
<form action="website.py" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
</form>
```

In your Python script, the code looks correct, but the issue might be with the server configuration or the way the form data is being sent. Make sure that the server is properly configured to handle POST requests and that website.py is set up to execute as a CGI script.

If the server is set up correctly and the HTML form is correct, the Python code should work. Here’s an example of how you can handle the form data in Python:

Python

```
import CGI

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
user_name = form.getvalue('username')

if user_name:
    print(f"Hello, {user_name}!")
else:
    print("Username not provided!")
```

Make sure to run this in a CGI-enabled server environment. If you’re still facing issues, check the server logs for any errors that might give you more insight into what’s going wrong.